# Updating a table with a function in SQL

Tags: sql

Say I want to take average of a set of numbers I have in a table and want to put that average in another column in the same table. How would I do that?

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Going to need more info: Start with--what have you already done/are you getting errors?

Comment: Well actually this was kind of a generalized question, what I actually want to do is this:     name      | ab  | r  | h  | hr | rbi | bb | k  
----------------+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----
 Wilson Ramos   | 107 |  9 | 34 |  1 |  16 |  4 | 17
 Albert Pujols  | 121 | 15 | 28 |  5 |  13 |  9 | 16
 Chase Utley    | 106 |  9 | 13 |  3 |  15 |  8 | 19
 Nolan Arenado  | 109 | 15 | 32 |  6 |  17 |  5 | 11
 Hanley Ramirez | 111 | 20 | 29 | 10 |  22 |  8 | 18
(5 rows)

Comment: I have this table and i want to implement this function (((h-hr)/(ab-k-hr)) and put the results back in the same table.

Comment: That should just be a simple `UPDATE` statement

Comment: I know i can use SELECT name, (((h-hr)/(ab-k-hr)) AS babip FROM hitters, but i want to know how to save it into the original table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try....

```
UPDATE hitters SET ColumnName = (((h-hr)/(ab-k-hr))
```

Comment: yep, what he said. mark his as the answer once you verify.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [tblname]
SET [columnname] = ([h]-[hr])/([ab]-[k]-[hr])
```